# How do I inject a constructor dependency into a ViewModel using Xamarin and Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a ViewModel and I want to inject another Class into it. I am using Visual Studio with the latest version of Xamarin. I'm using Autofac for registering en resolving dependencies. But I'm new to it and I'm facing a problem which I can't find the solution to, even though it's probably simple.

This is the Class in which I want to inject another Class:

```
public IMessagingCenterWrapper MessagingCenterWrapper;

public LoginViewModel(IMessagingCenterWrapper messagingCenterWrapper){
            MessagingCenterWrapper = messagingCenterWrapper;
        }
```

Then in entry point of the app I have a function which initializes the container which registers and resolves dependencies

```
static IContainer container{ get; set; }

public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeIOCContainer();
        }

void InitializeIOCContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<LoginViewModel>();
            builder.RegisterType<MessagingCenterWrapper>().As<IMessagingCenterWrapper>();
            container = builder.Build();

            var wrapper = container.Resolve<IMessagingCenterWrapper>();
            var viewModel = container.Resolve<LoginViewModel>();
        }
```

But I get an error when building at the line in the login View:

```
 BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
```

I'm getting the error because I don't initialize the parameter in the call.

But if I do that won't I destroy the whole principle of the IoC pattern. Eventually new class calls will be nested with other dependencies and I want to avoid that.

So my question is: how do I actually inject the the class parameter in the constructor?

Comment: When doing `BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();` you *are not using the DI container* at all.

Comment: @Fildor Can you explain how it's done then? Because the container is a private variable of the App entrypoint class and `BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();` is called in the View.

Comment: I admit I don't know the best practice for Autofac. But I see the container is static in App. So you could add a static Property that resolves the instance in the getter.

Comment: You might want to start [here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html).

Comment: @Fildor if I understand you correctly then you mean making the static property public and doing this: `BindingContext = new LoginViewModel(App.container.Resolve<IMessagingCenterWrapper>());` won't that make everything depend on the container? Which is the same as the service locater anti-pattern.

Comment: @ciyan97 No, that's not what I meant. It's too broad for a comment. I was hoping for some Autofac-Crack to write an answer. See, I've been using another DI container, so far and merely know of the existence of Autofac.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.DataGrid/blob/master/Simple.Wpf.DataGrid/BootStrapper.cs

Comment: ... in conjunction with this: https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.DataGrid/blob/master/Simple.Wpf.DataGrid/App.xaml.cs

Comment: @Steven I already started there. The problem is that the getting started guide shows an example, which is great, and at the end they add a note which says that the implementation is an anti-pattern. Without really mentioning how to make an implementation which resolves everything from the top of the application.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for your time and help. If I'm honest the code looks complex and I don't really know how I would implement this in my application. I wasted too much time trying to figure this out (half a day) and I decided that I will do the injection manually. For now, my application isn't too complex and in the time I tried to figure this out, I could already be done. Sorry for wasting the time you tried to help me, I really appreciate someone trying to help me.

Comment: Calling `Resolve<T>` is not an anti-pattern. You are mistaken. You _need_ to call `Resolve<T>` to be able to let Autofac create the object for you. What they are trying to tell you is that calling `Resolve<T>` from _anywhere but_ the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) *is* an anti-pattern. To be able to resolve a root object, you will _have_ to call `Resolve<T>`. There is no way around that.

Comment: What you could do in WPF is to resolve the View, and then call view.Show();. The view would take in the LoginViewModel as a parameter in the constructor, and then in the first line you set the DataContext to the LoginViewModel parameter.

Comment: @Steven All right, thank you for the article and the information. There is just one thing I don't understand because English isn't my first language. When you say _anywhere but_ does that mean that I need to resolve my objects in the Composition root (app.cs) or do I need to resolve the moment a new object is needed e.g. _When a view binds a new ViewModel_?

Comment: @ciyan97: You are allowed to have multiple calls to `Resolve<T>` as long as those calls are part of your Composition Root. In other words, the application's entry point is allowed to depend on a DI Container, but the rest of your application isn't. This probably means that the the code that binds a viewmodel to a view should be located in the entry point as well, to prevent it from being repeated throughout the application.

Answer (score -4):

This is actually a service locator injection, since the injected element is a messaging center service.  That's good news.

You don't have to pass in service constructors to view model constructors. Just request the service where you need it:

```
public LoginViewModel()  
{  
   MessagingCenterWrapper = App.Container.Resolve<IMessagingCenterWrapper>();  
}
```

Don't stick the view models into AutoFac unless they are indeed global.  There are a lot of problems with this sort of fake IOC.

To make it easier overall, how about this:

```
// MUST BE PUBLIC 
public static IContainer Container{ get; set; }

static App()  
{
   InitializeIOCContainer();  
} 

public App () 
{    
   InitializeComponent(); 
}

private static void InitializeIOCContainer() 
{    
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();    
   builder.RegisterType<MessagingCenterWrapper>().As<IMessagingCenterWrapper>();
   Container = builder.Build();

   // Don't stick view models in the container unless you need them globally, which is almost never true !!!

   // Don't Resolve the service variable until you need it !!!! }
}
```

The complete code for these remarks is at https://github.com/marcusts/xamarin-forms-annoyances.  See the solution called AwaitAsyncAntipattern.sln.

The GitHub site also provides links to a more detailed discussion on this topic.

Comment: Service locator is an established anti-pattern.